# Error running my first scrapy project

Tags: python, web, scrapy, pip

Hello after trying to instally scrapy for a whole day now. It's finally working.
However as I am totally new to Python. I don't think I've installed it correctly.

I tried to run my first scrapy project off of the scrapy.org manual (page 9)
but I got an error when I tried running the project.

Here's the error that I encountered :

```
[root@vnode01 sproject]# scrapy runspider quotes_spider.py -o quotes.json
2016-12-13 01:33:44 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.2.2 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-12-13 01:33:44 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_URI': 'quotes.json', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json'}
2016-12-13 01:33:45 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole']
2016-12-13 01:33:45 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-12-13 01:33:45 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-12-13 01:33:45 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-12-13 01:33:45 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2016-12-13 01:33:45 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

2016-12-13 01:33:45 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 74, in crawl
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

and the version of python that I'm using is :

```
[root]# cd ~
[root]# python -V
Python 3.5.2
[root]# pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [sqlite3 is part of Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html). It is strange that it's not available on your system. If you type `import sqlite3` in a `python` shell, do you have the same error? If yes, Python 3.5 is probably not correctly installed on your system (at least for sqlite3 dependency)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like Scrapy issue to me. You probably need to explicitly install `libsqlite3-dev` (assuming you're on Debian based system) or `sqlite-devel` (if you're on Redhat family)